# Unable to resolve (module) from App.js - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm brand new to React Native, and am already stuck at a seemingly obvious problem.

So I get an error

> Unable to resolve "src/AppNavigator" from "App.js"

when I try to access my AppNavigator from App.js. Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigator from 'src/AppNavigator';

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

and project structure:

```
-App.js
-babel.config.js
-index.js (what do you even use this for?)
-app.json
-package.json
-package-lock.json
-src
  |_ AppNavigator.js
  |_ react-native.config.js
  |_ screens
  |   |_ //...
  |_ assets
      |_ //...
-android
  |_ //...
-ios
  |_ //...
-__tests__
  |_ //...
-node_modules
  |_ //...
```

I've tried solutions outlined in this [github thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908), among others, but none seem to work (not exactly surprising as any documentation becomes obsolete after 6 months...), so I am stuck!

I've tried replacing `src/AppNavigator` with `./AppNavigator` and `../AppNavigator` for good measure, but that didn't work either.

Anyway know what's going on here?

Comment: Please can you write your AppNavigator.js content. May be you forgot export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add **./** before the path and also since AppNavigator.js is inside the *src* you have to write the below import code to run it successfully.
Just replace it with the below code and it will work like a charm....

```
import AppNavigator from './src/AppNavigator';
```

> Note :- .. will make you to go out of your current directory.

Hope this helps...Thanks :)

Comment: hi @Kc_dev, hope it helps. As a new user, you can upvote the answer as well thanks :)

Comment: I already did, but github doesn't reflect it until i have 15 reputation.